# listbox drag and drop items, items name

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have some function

```
private void listBox2_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        ListItemEl el = new ListItemEl();
        el.ui = files[i];
        listBox2.Items.Add(el);
    }
}
```

the row:

```
(string[])e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.DataFormats.FileDrop, false)
```

return file location.

Which function returns me from DragEventArgs name of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the full path just get the filename with Path.GetFileName

```
var files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
foreach (var filename in files)
{
    var nameOnly = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);
}
```